# SAPUI5 oModel.getJSON() isn't working when I use a JSON file as origin

Tags: json, getjson, sapui5

I created my Model using a JSON file.

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel( jsonFileUrl ); //JSON from file
```

It worked and the element was populated as I wanted.
But after this, when I tried to use oModel.getJSON() to get the JSON data it didn't work.

If I use an variable with the same content as the file, it works!

You can check the full test that I created:
https://googledrive.com/host/0B2gJUv6a_V1dYnNSV0ZsTFhxazg/index.html

Is there anybody to help me to understand what on Earth is happening here?

Comment: Which browser are you using? docs for this method say it does not work on ie8. If you try on chrome, do you see any error on the console? (ctr+shift+i > console) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because at the time you try to emit the JSON here:

```
$("#jsonFile").append(oModelFile.getJSON());
```

the actual ajax request to retrieve the file hasn't completed, and so the JSON model isn't filled at that time.

Wrap this in a handler for the requestCompleted event like this and it will work:

```
oModelFile.attachRequestCompleted(function() {
  $("#jsonFile").append(oModelFile.getJSON());
});
```