# Binding a Drop Down in SAPUI5 to list all possible values

Tags: sapui5, hana-xs

I've been able to successfully bind a DropDown control in SAPUI5 to list values based on one model. My questions is: how do I bind a DropDown to one model that contains all possible values and one model that contains the actual value for that record?

Example:

Table (and first Model)

**Name    School**

John    Hopkins

Mary    Horner

The school column is a DropDown, if I bind the DropDown to this model these are the only two schools that show up when in actuality there are five possible schools to choose based on the following model:

Second Model

**School**

- American
- Hopkins
- Horner
- Thornton
- Walters

Thought this would be simple, but haven;t been able to figure it out or find an example with searches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not quite sure I understand what you want to do exactly, but you can easily bind the selectedKey property to a different model than the one the items are filled from:

I created an example for you: http://jsbin.com/qipedoyufa/12/edit?html,js,output

It doesn't matter if the path points to the same model or a different one. I used named models and put the name of the model in front of the path, separated by ">". A Model named "x" with a path "/a/b/c" becomes "x>/a/b/c".

Update:
I think I now know what you meant, here is an example in a Table:
http://jsbin.com/tefijezete/2/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Bravo on answering something that didn't understand in the first place! I too was puzzled at what the OP was looking for, but your answer, particularly the 2nd link, made me understand the question ;)

Comment: Apologies on not clearly stating the question. I was trying to do it as clearly as possible without any coding examples, but yes I believe what you answered is what I am looking for. Currently trying to implement the selectedKey piece and will vote your answer up as soon as it works.  Thanks!!

Comment: An update: I think it's working properly for me. I had one follow up question. 

Does a DropDown box allow an empty value? For fields that don't have a value in the tableModel for school, it defaults to the first value. This also happens when I modify your example and remove the school value from any row.

Comment: You can just use a special key like "" and set the text to "" or "Please select school..."? http://jsbin.com/heleracobo/1/edit?js,output

Comment: Thank you, now I am having another issue .... let me try to explain it in the best way I can simply.


When I create my JSON Model the same way it is created in the jsbin, everything works fine. In my application, I have to make a server request through AJAX to an XSJS file that queries tables and constructs a JSON string. The XSJS returns the JSON string as contentType "application/json". The json loads appropriately in the table and data is showing; however, the selected key is no longer working. The path is exactly the same way I set up the structure above. Am I missing something here?

Comment: As I'm debugging, another interesting tidbit ..... the .getJSON() method for the local JSON model returns a result, the .getJSON() method for the XSJS JSON model returns empty brackets {}

Comment: Apologies for the spam, I'm slowly piecing together the puzzle. I was able to return JSON data after looking at this thread:

[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23960897/sapui5-omodel-getjson-isnt-working-when-i-use-a-json-file-as-origin)

and using the .attachRequestCompleted method. I have more to look into to slowly figure this out.

Comment: You could load the data with loadData and set the async argument to false, but that's of course not a very good solution. Attaching to requestCompleted is way better (see https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel.html#loadData)